# Saving a GeoTIFF with transparent data using OSGeo.Gdal

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, transparency-opacity, osgeo

I'm creating a GeoTIFF using OSGeo.Gdal and have been successful so far. However, it's unclear to me how to save a .tif file with transparency.

I'm building the GeoTIFF using a byte array where values of 0 should be transparent.

Here's a snippet of relevant code:

```
Driver driver = Gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff");
string[] options = new string[] { "BLOCKXSIZE=" + 64, "BLOCKYSIZE=" + 64, "TILED=YES" };

Dataset dataset = driver.Create(outputFile, outputWidth, outputHeight, 1, DataType.GDT_Byte, options);
var rasterBand = dataset.GetRasterBand(1);
rasterBand.DeleteNoDataValue();
rasterBand.SetNoDataValue(0);
rasterBand.WriteRaster(0, 0, outputWidth, outputHeight, imageByteData, outputWidth, outputHeight, 0, 0);

dataset.FlushCache();
dataset.Dispose();
```

For reasons I can't share the GeoTIFF image. But, you can visualize it as seafloor sonar data. Data appears on the left and right of a black strip in the middle - the black strip is what I want to be transparent.

I can't find any documentation that explains how to use osgeo to tell a TIFF file to save '0' values as transparent. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or if there's a setting I'm missing?

**EDIT:**
Added in SetNoDataValue(0) for the raster band (as suggested by the comment below). The saved .tif file still doesn't show any transparency.

Comment: You do not save '0' values as transparent, you just save '0' values and then you'll tell in the metadata that zeroes mean nodata. See examples containing  SetNoDataValue in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gcore/tiff_write.py.

Comment: @user30184 I added in SetNoDataValue(0) on the raster band but the saved .tif image still doesn't have transparency. It seems like a pretty straightforward function call - I'm wondering if there's something I need to be doing different with my 'options' or how I save/write the raster.

Comment: How did you check the transparency? The client must also be aware of the meaning of the nodata tag. Does gdalinfo now show this information `NoData Value=0`?

Comment: @user30184 I'm checking transparency at the point of the .tif file being saved into the Windows file system. The service I'm writing creates a .tif and publishes it to Mapserver. The transparency WORKS properly when displayed via mapserver. However, I expect the transparency to also be reflected in the actual .tif file saved in Windows Explorer. I'm giving the user the ability to export these .tif files displayed via Mapserver, and would like the exported .tif files to have the transparency, hence my desire to see the transparency when opening the file manually via Windows Explorer.

Comment: Also, NoData does return a value of 0 after running SetNoDataValue(0) on the raster band.

Comment: The Windows photo viewer does not understand NoData. The core TIFF specification does not define nodata (TIFF Tag GDAL_NODATA), it is an extension to the standard https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/gdal_nodata.html. GIS software are usually nodata-aware but for photo viewers you must handle the transparency with an alpha band.